# Error when installing ubuntu-zfs

Tags: zfs

I'm switching from FreeNAS to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  After a vanilla install of Ubuntu has been completed I run the following commands in the order shown to install ZFS:

1. `apt-get install python-software-properties`
2. `add-apt-repository ppa:zfs-native/stable`
3. `apt-get -y -q update && apt-get -y -q upgrade`
4. `apt-get install ubuntu-zfs`

When the last command is run ZFS is installed and ***seems*** to be working correctly... mostly (more on that later).  However, when the last command is run I get this error (full log [here](http://pastebin.com/yan2Sby3)):

```
configure: error:
        *** Please make sure the kmod spl devel <kernel> package for your
        *** distribution is installed then try again.  If that fails you
        *** can specify the location of the spl objects with the
        *** '--with-spl-obj=PATH' option.
```

What is this error and how do I fix it?

Now I said mostly earlier because my pool's don't auto mount when the server restarts the way they should.   All my reading (mostly from [this](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-ZFS-mountall-FAQ-and-troubleshooting) page) indicates that `mountall` should just take care of the mounting.  I have followed the instructions on that page and I cannot get `mountall` to work correctly.  My pools will only auto mount on restart if I edit `/etc/fstab` or change the `ZFS_MOUNT` and `ZFS_UNMOUNT` options in `/etc/default/zfs`.

Answer (score 6):

The following helped me on 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get remove spl-dkms zfs-dkms ubuntu-zfs
sudo apt-get install spl-dkms
sudo apt-get install zfs-dkms
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-zfs
```

I didn't realize that `spl` needs to be installed before `zfs` can be compiled successfully and I think I kept getting compile errors based on that fact. The gist, as I understand it, is that the `zfs` source depends on the `spl` source.

I found this information on [a mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/zfs-discuss/2014-04/msg00369.html).

Comment: +1 At my side the `apt-get remove` (`apt-get purge`) did the trick, as `apt-get install` nor `dpkg-reconfigure` helped.  Dunno why.

Answer (score 4):

You need to re-initialise your kernel stuff.. Just found the same issue on a fresh install here..

The following assumes you have the repo `ppa:zfs-native/stable` installed:

Firstly before attempting to install the stuff needed to compile::

```
apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential -y
```

Install zfs

```
apt-get install ubuntu-zfs -y
```

Rebuild the dkms drivers (SPL first)

```
dpkg-reconfigure spl-dkms
dpkg-reconfigure zfs-dkms
```

If all went well you should be able to load the module and see them loaded:

```
# modprobe zfs
# lsmod | grep zfs
zfs                  1144227  0 
zunicode              331251  1 zfs
zavl                   15010  1 zfs
zcommon                47181  1 zfs
znvpair                88812  2 zfs,zcommon
spl                   168728  5 zfs,zavl,zunicode,zcommon,znvpair
```

This is all the "simple" version of what I found here: https://groups.google.com/a/zfsonlinux.org/d/msg/zfs-discuss/sSTbgwerXi4/txQ9EK2yqMMJ

I used this on my workstation for what its worth, about the same as the two dpkg rebuilds above:

```
KERNEL_VER=`uname -r`
ZFS_VER=0.6.2

dkms remove -m spl -v $ZFS_VER --all 
dkms remove -m zfs -v $ZFS_VER --all

ls -l /var/lib/dkms/spl /var/lib/dkms/zfs   # (should be nothing there)

dkms add -m sqpl -v $ZFS_VER -k KERNEL_VER
dkms install -m spl -v $ZFS_VER -k $KERNEL_VER

dkms add -m zfs -v $ZFS_VER -k KERNEL_VER
dkms install -m zfs -v $ZFS_VER -k $KERNEL_VER
```

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of trial and error I found that calling `apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential` before any of the other commands resulted in the later call to `apt-get install ubuntu-zfs` executing without error.  That still didn't fix the `mountall` problem though :(