# Failed to load ZFS module stack

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, zfs, dkms

Have been using zfs on linux (zfs-native/stable) raidz on 14.04 for several months without hitch and decided to move across some more important files as considered it trustworthy or I guess "stable" (only a recent foray into linux world).

Yesterday I performed an upgrade as a recommendation to fix an error message at ubuntu startup (did not fix) and now find that myzfs pool is no longer.   I tried to re-mount and receive this error:

```
Failed to load ZFS module stack. 
Load the module manually by running 'insmod <location>/zfs.ko' as root. 
Failed to load ZFS module stack. 
Load the module manually by running 'insmod <location>/zfs.ko' as root.
```

After some websearches I found [this](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/1155) solution from dajhorn which I partly attempted.

```
dkms status
spl, 0.6.3, 3.13.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
zfs, 0.6.2, 3.13.0-24-generic, x86_64: installed
zfs, 0.6.2, 3.13.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
```

As the versions differ I decided to remove zfs 0.6.2 `sudo dkms remove -m zfs -v 0.6.2 --all` and thought a solution would be to replace with zfs 0.6.3.  Is this the right way to go about things still?  I am just concerned that dajhorn's post is 2 years old and am absolutely paranoid about losing data.

Alternatively is an approach such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431879/error-when-installing-ubuntu-zfs) more suitable/relevant to my problem?

So to sum up, at this stage I removed zfs 0.6.2 and am hoping for some advice on best approach to resolve- should I still trust a 2 year old post or take different approach.  Thanks for taking time to read and I hope you are able to help.

Further information:

Install method...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zfs-native/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-zfs

apt-cache policy spl spl-dkms ubuntu-zfs zfs-dkms
spl:
  Installed: 0.6.3-1~trusty
  Candidate: 0.6.3-1~trusty
  Version table:
 *** 0.6.3-1~trusty 0
       1001 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zfs-native/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
spl-dkms:
  Installed: 0.6.3-1~trusty
  Candidate: 0.6.3-1~trusty
  Version table:
 *** 0.6.3-1~trusty 0
       1001 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zfs-native/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
ubuntu-zfs:
  Installed: 7~trusty
  Candidate: 8~trusty
  Version table:
     8~trusty 0
       1001 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zfs-native/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7~trusty 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
zfs-dkms:
  Installed: 0.6.2-2~trusty
  Candidate: 0.6.3-3~trusty
  Version table:
     0.6.3-3~trusty 0
       1001 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zfs-native/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.6.2-2~trusty 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

modprobe:  FATAL: Module zfs not found.
```

=============
After

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

No errors returned and packages all seem to be upgraded (spl 0.6.3-1, spl-dkms 0.6.3-1, ubuntu-zfs 8~trusty, zfs-dkms 0.6.3-3).

Now check:

```
sudo zpool list no pools available
```

check: `zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id` 
Everything looks okay.. so I imported. All OK!!

Before ending, am I missing something else that would be worthwhile checking?

Thanks.

Comment: You appear to have mixed spl and zfs packages with 0.6.2 and 0.6.3 versions which may cause the problem. I think you have installed the ZoL packages in a non-recommended way. Are you using the ZoL PPA or not? Please provide the output of `apt-cache policy spl spl-dkms ubuntu-zfs zfs-dkms` in your question by [edit]ing it. Please also include the lines appearing in `/var/log/syslog` when attempting to run `modprobe zfs`.

Comment: You're not up-to-date in some packages and it's indeed a mismatch in versions! It shows clearly that you did not upgrade zfs (0.6.2, but 0.6.3 available), but you did upgrade spl (0.6.3). Just make sure you upgrade all packages first: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and try again. If you still have issues, please also include the kernel version you're running: `uname -r` and all error messages from the upgrade process by `apt-get` (if any).

Comment: Thank you, thank you ! Your install method got my problem solved. I had the stack couldnt be loaded error, removed the modules but they would not compile again. 3.13 kernel. Your steps upgraded and installed the dkms spl and zfs to the latest stables! Phew!