# zpool missing after kernel upgrade attempt

Tags: 14.04, zfs

I'm running 14.04 LTS with ZFS and tried to update my kernel to 3.17 following [these instructions](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-kernel-3-17-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-and-derivatives/). During this install I got this error:

```
    *** Please make sure the kmod spl devel <kernel> package for your
    *** distribution is installed then try again.  If that fails you
    *** can specify the location of the spl objects with the
    *** '--with-spl-obj=PATH' option.
```

Google led me to [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431879/error-when-installing-ubuntu-zfs), and I ran `sudo apt-get install spl-dkms` to attempt to fix the above.

After reboot, I have kernel 3.17 but no ZFS pools. I rolled back to my previous kernel (3.13.0-40) but still have no zpools.

```
$ sudo zpool status
no pools available
```

I should have one mirror pool showing. The partitions are still there, as parted shows:

```
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA HGST HTS721010A9 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name    Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB               boot0   bios_grub
 2      2097kB  10.0GB  9998MB               root0
 3      10.0GB  992GB   982GB   zfs          zdata0
 5      992GB   1000GB  8204MB               swap0
```

The other drive looks similar. The mirror is on zdata0 and zdata1.

Why can't it find my zpool, and how do I get it back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, `zdb` showed the pool, but `zpool status` did not. I needed to do:

```
zpool import -f zdata
```

And all was well again.

Comment: Yes, but after reboot, zpool will disappear again.

Comment: @Xdg, didn't in my case. Working fine ever since.

Comment: Thanks. You were on 14.04. In 15.10, I had to add zpool import tank into /etc/rc.local .

Comment: This worked great on 16.04. I shutdown and removed two drives, upon reboot the pool was completely missing, very odd. This fixed my issue though.